# How to Navigate through Ext-JS Code?

Tags: eclipse, extjs

I'm having a tough time learning Javascript/Ext-JS.  I setup the Spket plug-in for some Code Completion in Eclipse, but like for instance, if I see a piece of code like this....

```
Ext.ComponentMgr.get('communicationName').findById('showBannerId').add(
{
     xtype : 'displayfield',
     id : 'bannerField',
     value : banners,
     autoHeight : true,
     width : 1000
});
```

Spket highlights the .get red so I can't code complete further then the get(). Aside from trying to look for showBannerId (which I found was a table... it had the layout:'table' member).  Where in Ext-JS API could I of found that this Ext-JS member had a method called 'add'?

**Side Note of why I am looking at this piece of code:

Essentially I need to make sure this showBannerId doesn't continually add these displayFields.  The id bannerField should be checked to see:

-If it exists (***which I just figured out***) Ext.get('bannerField'); and

-If it exists then it should only edit the displayField... not recreate it.  How can I edit its attributes (***researching xtype displayfield's setValue method)***?

Hopefully this makes sense... let me know if I wasn't clear.

Comment: In order to answer your specific question (i.e. how to prevent `showBannerId` from being continually called), more details are necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resources**

The [ExtJS Documentation](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/) and [Examples](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/) Should be your number one source of information regarding ExtJS.

**Discovering methods / objects**

In your particular case, how would you know that the element in question had an `add` method? You would basically have to look at the functions that you are calling in the documentation, and what they are expected to return. For example, you call [`Ext.ComponentMgr.get`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.ComponentMgr). In the documentation, this returns an [`Ext.Component`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Component). Worth noting, however, is that there are many ExtJS objects that inherit from `Ext.Component` (in fact, most objects inherit from it!).

Programmatically, you can determine the actual type of an `Ext.Component` by calling `getXType`, or `isXType(type)` to check that something is a certain type of component (The [`Ext.Component`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Component) documentation has a list of xtypes and their corresponding classes). Based on what you've written though, if you want to know what kind of a component you have, you might be better off looking through your source code for the id in question (i.e. `showBannerId`), and seeing how it is declared, or what object it is declared as a part of.

**Your specific question**

If you want to...

- Check if a field exists; and
- Edit it, if it does

The following code will be of help to you:

```
var elem = Ext.getCmp("bannerField") //Shorthand for Ext.ComponentMgr.get
//check if a field exists:
if(!Ext.isEmpty(elem)) {

    //make sure it is the right type
    if(elem.isXType('displayfield')) {
        elem.setValue(banners) //since we know this is an Ext.form.DisplayField component
    }

} else {
    //element does not exist, so add it
    Ext.ComponentMgr.get('communicationName').findById('showBannerId').add({
        xtype : 'displayfield',
        id : 'bannerField',
        value : banners,
        autoHeight : true,
        width : 1000
    });
}
```

Note that I use `Ext.getCmp` (which gets an `Ext.component`) as opposed to `Ext.get` (which gets an `Ext.Element`; essentially, a wrapper for a DOM object).

**Tools**

If you are looking for good tools for working with ExtJS, I'd recommend taking a look at [Illumination](http://www.illuminations-for-developers.com/), a firebug extension that allows you to peek into ExtJS objects more easily than looking at raw javascript objects. If you're looking for good IDE support for javascript and ExtJS... that's a whole other question! Support for javascript in IDE's is generally not great.

Comment: Thanks for the Info!  Although I don't see the add method within the Ext.Component in the API... unless I'm just not looking correctly.

Comment: You are looking correctly... I just neglected a detail (which I will include in an edit)

Comment: Hey I tweaked my question a bit... see if that makes better sense.  Again thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I really appreciate it.  Being a java developer lets me get used to so many crutches haha.  Also apparently Spket has a problem with the .get() call I was using see here http://forums.spket.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1911&p=3163#p3163

Comment: There are certainly a lot more robust tools for Java development! I'm glad that my answer was of help to you.